# Updating a go asset path for Git forks

Tags: git, go, github, assets, git-fork

So I have this line in my code:

`base := build.Default.GOPATH + "/src/github.com/skuzzymiglet/point/"`

Later, I use it like this:

`script, err := ioutil.ReadFile(base + "script.js")`

The problem with this is if someone forks my repo, it will reference my assets not theirs, and possibly end up with an error.

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Don't fork. Github forks create new, unrelated and possible unworking packages. Do not try. It does not work.

Comment: But what if they want to make a pull request?

Comment: You _clone_ the repo. This is what is working. For PRs you make a fork, push to the fork and make the PR. But the fork is _not_ valid. Go package.

Answer (score 0):

> it will reference my assets not theirs, and possibly end up with an error.

Then:

- either that asset must be part of the repository being forked
- or it must be generated or downloaded as a dependency, for instance part of a Go module.

Comment: So should they go in a separate github repo?

Comment: @RHarrington That is possible too, and then added to your repo as a submodule.